# evaluate boolean expression in java generate at runtime

Tags: java, runtime, generator, boolean-expression, expression-evaluation

How to evaluate complex boolean expressions generated at runtime in a Java program?

Example:

(x and y or z) and s

with x, y, z boolean variables ...

Thanks

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  What's wrong with `if ((x && y || z) && s)`?

Comment: Can you give a code example showing how you represent your expressions?

Comment: The expressions are loaded from an xml file, but the Boolean variables take different values according to the current state of the program. So I can not use an if as suggested above because it is not always the same expression ...

Comment: Well, then you'll have to build a parser (nothing big, but supporting nesting - so don't even thing of regex!), build an AST and evaluate that with a mapping variable names => bools.

Comment: @delnan Maybe even easier to use PEP http://www.ling.ohio-state.edu/~scott/#projects-pep to parse it and then do as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JANINO/Home for minimum work. I can do much more than simple expressions.

Comment: On the page I pointed to, http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JANINO/Basic. The very first example should suffice, just change the types to boolean.

Comment: thanks, This is a simple and immediate solution that satisfies what I was interested.

Answer (score 1):

Very briefly, you need an "intermediate representation" of the Boolean expressions.  This is a tree formed of `Node` objects.  `Node` has ths subclasses `AndNode`, `OrNode`, `NotNode`, and `VariableNode`.  An `AndNode` has two child `Node`s, an `OrNode` has two child `Node`s, and a `NotNode` has one child `Node`.

A `VariableNode` has just a variable name String, eg, "x".  You would have a `HashMap<String, Boolean>` where each variable name key has an associated Boolean value.

Each Node class has an `eval()` method that evaluates its expression and returns a `boolean`.  The `VariableNode.eval()` method looks up the value of the variable in your `HashMap` and returns it.  `NotNode.eval()` returns `!child.eval()`.  `AndNode.evaluate()` returns `child1.eval() && child2.eval()`, while `OrNode.evaluate()` returns `child1.eval() || child2.eval()`.  To evaluate an entire Boolean expression tree, just call the root node's `eval()` method.

You can build these Boolean expression trees programmatically, using Java constructors, etc.

If you want to build your expression trees from strings, you'll need to write a parser that produces a tree from a string.  Terence Parr's [Language Implementation Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193435645X) is a very simple and clear introduction to this.

Comment: This approach worked great for me. I've also implemented a visual expression editor UI in a JSF webapp using the Tomahawk treeview control to display the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

How to evaluate a logical expression? Logical expressions such as those can be evaluated as a syntax tree, and I think that there's some good information in this related question [Logic expression parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826717/logic-expression-parser)

The other thing that springs to mind is that you want to be able to handle logical expressions as data, which seems like something more suited to a scripting language like maybe Jython, JRuby, Groovy or Scala (assuming you're restricted to the JVM). Although I doubt it'd be very hard to write a parser to handle basic and/or/not logical expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to generate an expression tree and bind each leaf to a boolean value. For parsing this expression and generating an AST take a look at Dijkstra's [Shunting Yard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) algorithm. Everything is explained in there and is fairly straight forward to implement.